# Abrir Página Direto no Centro

Tags: javascript, html

É possível quando abrir a página carregar direto no centro dela sem precisar de âncora e também sem scroll ?

Tudo que eu pesquiso se relaciona com `window.open()`.
Não achei algo específico do que eu preciso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi da seguinte maneira:

`$(document).scrollTop($(window).height() / 2);`

Meu documento abrirá no centro da página, fazendo tamanho da tela dividido por 2.

Enfim, mosquei.

Comment: Não era para ser `sem precisar de âncora e também sem scroll`?

Comment: Mas a página já abre direto no centro. Quando disse scroll quis dizer rolar. A página estava abrindo e rolando até onde eu queria.

Comment: você queria sem animação de rolagem então né?

Comment: Isso mesmo Charles.

Answer (score 1):

É possível direcionar para um elemento especifico:

`http://www.minhapagina.com/#centro`

Ou seja, ao entrar na página principal, basta redirecionar para o mesmo endereço adicionando `#` + id do elemento!

Comment: Mas eu falei que não quero âncora. Mas obrigado. Já consegui resolver aqui.